# Custom sorting for agenda

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to build custom agenda block which would sort completed tasks by *CLOSED* property. `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` only supports ordering by *SCHEDULED* and *DEADLINE* properties, so I guess only way to implement this is to use custom sorting function with `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  ;; custom sorting for closed items (does not work)
  (defun my/org-custom-cmp (a b)
    (org-cmp-ts a b "closed")
    )

  (setq org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'my/org-custom-cmp)

  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("z" "Tasks Overview"
           ((tags "+TODO=\"DONE\"+CLOSED>\"<-3d>\"" ((org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'my/org-custom-cmp)
                                                     (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-up))
                                                     (org-agenda-max-entries 15)
                                                     (org-agenda-overriding-header "Recently Completed Tasks")))

            ))
;; ...
```

Comment: Please place your cursor on an  org-agenda result that contains a closed entry and `M-x eval-expression RET (message "%s" (text-properties-at (point)) RET` and see if there are any properties that indicate the closed date, and then either update your question or post a comment with the results.  I added text properties for many items in a custom version of org-mode, and I sent in a feature request to the org-mode team a couple of years ago to increase the sorting abilities.  The org-team responding by stating that fixes/enhancements were in the works.  What version of `org-mode` are you using?

Comment: I'm using `org-mode` version `8.3.5`, I've tried using `text-properties-at` (and `M-x describe-text-properties`), but couldn't find anything related to closed timestamp there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @lawlist said the entry's properties are stored in text properties of the corresponding lines in the agenda.  We just have to extract those using `get-text-property`.  Not every property makes it into the agenda, but there is an `org-marker` property telling us were the original data is.  We can use that to extract whatever we like using `org-entry-get`.

Here's a function that provides  a comparator based on any timestamp property:

```
(defun cmp-date-property (prop)
  "Compare two `org-mode' agenda entries, `A' and `B', by some date property.

If a is before b, return -1. If a is after b, return 1. If they
are equal return nil."
  (lexical-let ((prop prop))
  #'(lambda (a b)

    (let* ((a-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
           (b-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
           (a-date (or (org-entry-get a-pos prop)
                       (format "<%s>" (org-read-date t nil "now"))))
           (b-date (or (org-entry-get b-pos prop)
                       (format "<%s>" (org-read-date t nil "now"))))
           (cmp (compare-strings a-date nil nil b-date nil nil))
           )
      (if (eq cmp t) nil (signum cmp))
      ))))
```

Just set `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined` to `(cmp-date-property "CLOSED")` and it should work:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("z" "Tasks Overview"
               tags "+TODO=\"DONE\"+CLOSED>\"<-3d>\""
               ((org-agenda-cmp-user-defined (cmp-date-property
                                              "CLOSED"))
                (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-up)))))
```

Two things to note:  it compares the timestamps as strings which is basically fine using the default timestamp format, less fine otherwise; if the property in question doesn't exist it's value defaults to `<now>`.

Comment: Note that the docstring above should say ```
If they are equal return nil.
```