# org-agenda-sorting-strategy: items containing no time-of-day specification first

Tags: org-mode, sorting

The manual says

> For the daily/weekly agenda, the items for each day are sorted. The
>   default order is to first collect all items containing an explicit
>   time-of-day specification.

```
    8:30-13:00 Arthur Dent lies in front of the bulldozer
    12:45...... Ford Prefect arrives and takes Arthur to the pub
    14:00-15:00 TODO Call John regarding memo
    19:00...... The Vogon reads his poem
    20:30-22:15 Marvin escorts the Hitchhikers to the bridge
    TODO send newsletter to mailing list
    TODO buy John birthday gift           :errands:
    Internship period for Alex
```

How can I tweak `org-agenda-sorting-strategy' so that I can first display all items containing no time-of-day specification like in

```
    Internship period for Alex
    TODO send newsletter to mailing list
    TODO buy John birthday gift           :errands:
    8:30-13:00 Arthur Dent lies in front of the bulldozer
    12:45...... Ford Prefect arrives and takes Arthur to the pub
    14:00-15:00 TODO Call John regarding memo
    19:00...... The Vogon reads his poem
    20:30-22:15 Marvin escorts the Hitchhikers to the bridge
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `org-sort-agenda-notime-is-late` to `nil`. It is defined in org-agenda.el and, by default, the value is t (see also it's use in *org-cmp-time*).

> Non-nil means items without time are considered late.
>   This is only relevant for sorting.  When t, items which have no explicit
>   time like 15:30 will be considered as 99:01, i.e. later than any items which
>   do have a time.  When nil, the default time is before 0:00.  **You can use this
>   option to decide if the schedule for today should come before or after timeless
>   agenda entries**.

Answer (score 1):

Check the current setting of `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`. It should be something like this:

```
((agenda time-up priority-down category-keep)
 (todo priority-down category-keep)
 (tags priority-down category-keep)
 (search category-keep))
```

Changing the order of sorting strategies for the agenda should do what you want:

```
(setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy 
    '((agenda priority-down category-keep time-up)
      (todo priority-down category-keep)
      (tags priority-down category-keep)
      (search category-keep)))
```

Read the documentation of the variable for more information.

EDIT: As the OP points out in the comments, this does not work. It *should* be possible to do what he wants using a user-defined comparison function as described in my comment below, but that is TBD.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be compatible with time-grid.

Comment: You are right: the categories/priorities force the entries out of time order in the grid. The only other possibility I can think of is to set `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` to e.g. `user-defined-up` and then write your own `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined` function to impose the order that you want. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to do that now, but it should not be too difficult. If nobody comes up with one (or perhaps another method), I'll try to do one next weekend.

Comment: `(agenda todo-state-up time-up)` pretty much does what I want.  Except for the fact that I would like to see appointment with no time specification at the top of the list and not at the bottom.  I'll have a look at `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`

Comment: @Rene:  Place your cursor on the agenda entry that you wish to sort and see what text properties (in the agenda buffer) are present -- those are used for sorting.  If a particular property is missing, that value may need to be assigned during the gathering of data just prior to the population of the agenda buffer.  In my own setup, I assigned properties and so forth so that it's backed into the code.  There was an answer a few months ago that used `org-get-entry ...` and the `'org-marker` to extract a value from the original buffer during the data gathering process. . . .; so that's an idea.

Comment: @Rene -- here is the link to the thread I was thinking of in the previous comment:  "**Custom sorting for agenda**"  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26369/2287

Comment: Just found that using C-u C-x = on some entry let me see the list of available text properties that you can manipulate.