# Get repeating value for org entry

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, text-properties

I want to use the repeat-duration of tasks in the `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined` value of my custom agenda view.

For example, let's say I have the following task.

```
* TODO Reticulate Splines
SCHEDULED: <2018-04-14 Sat 00:00 +56h>
```

How can I extract `+56h` (or some representation thereof) from the text properties?

Comment: Have you examined the text-properties at point `(message "%s" (text-properties-at (point)))` to see if your `+56h` is there?  If it is not there, then it may be necessary to programmatically return to the original source buffer to extract that component -- this can be done so the user does not see the quick switch actually occurring.  Or, it may be necessary to extract that component from the text of the `*Org Agenda*` buffer if the text properties do not contain `+56h`.

Comment: Here is a link to an example of how to extract a component from the source buffer if a text-property does not already exist:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26369/2287